# Fetch thumbnail and article description from link

Tags: hyperlink, thumbnails, fetch

I'm developing a site where users will be able to post a link of news articles from some other site. I would like the thumbnail and the description to appear on my site.

So for example, a user could post this link [http://www.cnn.com/2012/10/04/politics/debate-next/index.html?hpt=hp_c1] from CNN on my site and its thumbnail and description would be published.

I see that facebook uses 'meta property="og:image"' and 'meta property="og:description"'. I would like to know if there's some script I can use to pull such data?

Thanks